# passing 'const list' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem passing a string inside a linked list that's set to const, I'm not sure how to pass a value from a const properly, any help would be greatly appreciated

```
class list
{
     public:
          // General Class Elements Required in CS 162
          list();                       // Default constructor
         ~list();                       // Default destructor
          list(const list &);           // Copy constructor
          list(list &&);                // Move constructor
          list(element *);              // Parm constructor
          list & operator = (const list &);// Copy assignment
          list & operator = (list &&);  // Move assignment

          friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &, const list &);
          friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream &, list &);

          // List ADT Elements
          bool           is_empty() const;                  // True if list is empty
          bool           is_full() const;                   // True if list is full
          element & operator[](std::size_t);                // Reference index
          const element & operator[](std::size_t) const;    // Value index
          const element & at(std::size_t);                  // Accessor
          element * find(element *);                        // Search
          bool      remove(std::size_t);                    // Positional deletion
          bool      remove(element *);                      // Value deletion (multiple deletions)
          bool      insert(element *, size_t);              // Positional insertion
          bool      insert(element *);                      // Ordered insertion
          bool      erase();                                // Erase all elements
          size_t    length() const;                         // Number of elements in list

     private:
          size_t    size;               // Size of the list
          size_t    capacity;           // Capacity of the list
          element * head;               // Head pointer
          element * tail;               // Tail pointer
};


          bool operator <  (const list &, const list &);
          bool operator <= (const list &, const list &);
          bool operator == (const list &, const list &);
          bool operator != (const list &, const list &);
          bool operator >= (const list &, const list &);
          bool operator >  (const list &, const list &);
```

```
    // Stream Operators // Stream Operators
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, const list & data) {
    size_t iter=0;
    while(iter!=data.length()) {
          out<< data.at(iter)->get_data()<<" ";//problem line
          iter++;
     }
```

```
const element& list::at(std::size_t loc) {
    element & temp;
    temp=head;
    for(size_t idx = 0; i<loc; i++){
        temp=temp->get_next();
    }
    const element & here = temp;
    return here;

}
```

the compiler passes an error saying

> "list.cpp: In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const list&)': list.cpp:103:23: error: passing 'const list' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] out << data.at(iter)->get_data() <<" ";"

what am I doing wrong? 
*edit: I added the definition of list*

Comment: Show the definition of `list`.

Comment: `at` should be defined as `const` if you wish to use it on const lists

Comment: and so does `length()`

Comment: How did you manage to not initialize a reference `element & temp;`? Looks weird for me.

Comment: @silvercricket This question is still on the list of unanswered questions. Didn't my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Just as you have:

```
      element& operator[](std::size_t);
const element& operator[](std::size_t) const;
```

you also need both these:

```
      element& list::at(std::size_t);
const element& list::at(std::size_t) const;
```

And `length()` must be `const` too, but you only need one of that:

```
std::size_t length() const;
```